# Generate private key from a bip-39 seed phrase?

Tags: private-key, hash, mnemonic-seed

I'm able to generate a new private key and associated public addresses using bitcoin-core, but what I really want to do is generate a new private key from a 24 word seed phrase. I'm not sure how to go about this and I have not been able to find any examples.

BIP-39 Word list:

```
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt
```

Current code:

```
var bitcore=require("bitcore-lib");
var buffer=bitcore.crypto.Random.getRandomBuffer(256);
var hash=bitcore.crypto.Hash.sha256(buffer);
var bn=bitcore.crypto.BN.fromBuffer(hash);
var pk=new bitcore.PrivateKey(bn).toWIF();
var address=new bitcore.PrivateKey(bn).toAddress()+'';
```

If I understand correctly I will generate a hash from 24 randomly selected words (from the BIP-39 word list) then use that to generate a private key. What are the steps and format for hashing the seed phrase?

Comment: The 24 seed words **can't be** arbitrarily chosen. For examples for synthesizing seed words look at https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-mnemonic-new#example-1.

Comment: Thank you. I am developing in a Windows NodeJS environment using bitcoin-core. These examples look to be some kind of command line operation with "bx" which is not recognized as anything executable in my environment.

Comment: At least you now have some test vector information when doing NodeJS work.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39

"A tool for converting BIP39 mnemonic phrases to addresses and private keys."

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core knows nothing of BIP39 seed phrases, since the developers never took those recommendations on board.

Comment: OP was asking about the bitcore JS library, not Bitcoin Core (though seems like they were confused about that themselves).

Answer (score -1):

Look at [**Example 7**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#7-bitcoin-btc-bip-3944-technology-examples).  There are also adjacent examples for other altcoins as well.

Comment: Thank you. I am developing in a Windows NodeJS environment using bitcoin-core. These examples look to be some kind of command line operation with "bx" which is not recognized as anything executable in my environment.